# Transposing a column with a line in a matrix

Tags: matrix, transpose

We have this matrix of 4x4:

> a b c d
>
> e f g h
>
> 1 2 3 4
>
> 5 6 7 8

By **transposing the matrix** we get:

> a e 1 5
>
> b f 2 6
>
> c g 3 7
>
> d h 4 8

My question is:

**What matrix do we get by "transposing column 2 with row 4?"**

I need to understand the operation in itself, what does it imply/mean? I never thought of "transposing a column with a line".

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, It means you are to swap column 2 and row 4, instead of column 1 with row 1 and column2 with row 2 etc.

The code is basically the same as a full transposition, except you only have one column/row

Answer (score 0):

[Matrix transposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_transposition) is a mathematical operation in which a matrix's rows become its columns.  From a mathematical perspective, there's no real benefit to transposing only one row in a *M x N* matrix, but the code to transpose one row is not much different than transposing an entire matrix.

The matrix you get after the transposition would be:

```
a b 1 d

e f 2 h

c g 3 7

5 6 4 8
```